# ServiceStack MessageFactory publishing

Tags: redis, messaging, servicestack

I have been reviewing the ServiceStack Messaging with Redis documentation here:

https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-redis

It seems to explain the basics very well.  What I don't quite understand though are differences and applicable use cases when publishing via the MessageFactory:

```
.CreateMessageProducer.Publish()
```

and

```
.CreateMessageQueueClient.Publish()
```

I plan on reviewing the code but wanted to post this here for an "official" explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are the API's of `IMessageProducer` and `IMessageQueueClient`:

```
public interface IMessageProducer : IDisposable
{
    void Publish<T>(T messageBody);
    void Publish<T>(IMessage<T> message);
}

public interface IMessageQueueClient : IMessageProducer
{
    void Publish(string queueName, byte[] messageBytes);
    void Notify(string queueName, byte[] messageBytes);
    byte[] Get(string queueName, TimeSpan? timeOut);
    byte[] GetAsync(string queueName);
    string WaitForNotifyOnAny(params string[] channelNames);
}
```

Basically a `MessageQueueClient` **is** also a `MessageProducer`, but contains other fine-grained methods in addition to Publish to **Get** messages off the queue as well as publish and subscribe to any MQ topics.

The typed `Publish<T>` API on both the message client and the producer have the same behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @mythz.  Not sure if this merits another SO question, but is IMessageProducer/IMessageFactory meant to be extended to support additional kinds of publishers (e.g. like SignalR)?  Thinking about specific SS message handlers that forward messages to other messaging systems w/o the the handler having to care about certain publishing mechanics (e.g. connectivity, IoC resolution).  Or do you recommend another approach for that?

Comment: ServiceStack's IMessageService APIs are designed so they're impl agnostic, but they're meant for MQ brokers like RabbitMQ/MSMQ or newer ServiceBus providers. I don't think a SignalR provider would be a perfect fit here, I would just treat SignalR integration as another `IDependency` and get your services to explicitly publish to that.